# cakephp : what is the meaning of first param in paginate('Recipe')

Tags: cakephp

i do not know the meaning and use of first param in paginate:

```
$data = $this->paginate('Recipe', array('Recipe.title LIKE' => 'a%'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not

a) using a proper IDE - than you could answer it yourself:

[image: example]

b) checking the well documented method online:

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php#L1070

Comment: book.cakephp.org/complete/1231/Pagination, why can i not find the model 'Recipe' ?

Comment: the code in the cookbook is an example, you must apply it to your own application and needs. There is no model `Recipe` unless you create one.

Answer (score 1):

First parameter indicates the name of the model

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/complete/1231/Pagination, why can i not find the model 'Recipe' ?

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter to `paginate()` is the model to be paginated. See the [API doc](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/paginator-component#method-PaginatorComponentpaginate).

Comment: book.cakephp.org/complete/1231/Pagination, why can i not find the model 'Recipe' ?